# PagedList parameter too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have an MVC PagedList which works just fine. I am filtering that list and the filter predicate is sent to the client during roundtrips. I use unobtusive ajax replacing. My pager code looks as:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Items,
        page => Url.Action("Filter", 
                new ClientSearch 
                { 
                    Page = page, 
                    PageSize = Model.PageSize, 
                    Predicate = Model.Predicate 
                }),
        PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
                new AjaxOptions 
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST", 
                    UpdateTargetId = "clients-list",
                }))
```

The problem is, that the Predicate parameter is too long. And it should be. I get the following exception:

"The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."

I do not want to alter the web.config in order to allow long parameters. I would like to pass the model in a POST header instead of query string parameter. Is it possible with PagedList?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't figure out whether PagedList supported posting large data, however I ended up with the following workaround.

I have a post method which posts the model to the controller function and replaces the partial view content with the results.

```
function postToPage(url, size, predicate, replace) {
    var data = {
        size: size,
        predicate: predicate
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#' + replace).html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I also have another function to replace the URLs in the pagination-container div and wire up the click event to call the post method. The click event stops event propagation, so the URL in the href attribute won't be used.

```
function replaceHrefs() {
    $('div[class = pagination-container').find('a').each(function (index, value) {
        var url = value.href.toString();
        value.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            post(url);
        });
        value.href = '#';
    });
```

I created a custom version of post method in order to generate the pagesize and predicate from the model.

```
function post(url) {
    postToPage(url, @Model.PageSize, '@Model.Predicate', 'clients-list');
}
```

I had to wire up the URL replacing procedure to two places: when the document becomes ready and when the ajax call completes. These covered all the cases I needed.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    replaceHrefs();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    replaceHrefs();
});
```

I hope it helps someone.